# Button to switch tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, html-table

I've made some buttons that whenever you press them it takes you to another table...

My problem is that the tables (already made/designed) aren't showing up-- only the data is.

The button themselves work but won't allow the tables to show, only the data.

I really, really appreciate any help.

Link to demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LpLhP/4/

Html:

```
<img src="img" alt="img goes here">
<p>
<a class="button" data-table="1" href="#">button1</a>

<a class="button" data-table="2" href="#">button2</a>

<a class="button" data-table="3" href="#">button3</a>

<a class="button" data-table="4" href="#">button4</a>




            <table id="1">   
            <div id="content">
            <a class="back" href="#"></a>
            <span class="scroll"></span>
            <p class="head">    
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Starter">Smart Starter</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Medium">Smart Medium</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Business">Smart Business</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Deluxe">Smart Deluxe</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>$ 2.90</td>
                        <td>$ 5.90</td>
                        <td>$ 9.90</td>
                        <td>$ 14.90</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>512 MB</td>
                        <td>1 GB</td>
                        <td>2 GB</td>
                        <td>4 GB</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>50 GB</td>
                        <td>100 GB</td>
                        <td>150 GB</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>19.90 $</td>
                        <td>12.90 $</td>
                        <td>free</td>
                        <td>free</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

    <table id="2">
           <div id="content">
            <a class="back" href="#"></a>
            <span class="scroll"></span>
            <p class="head">    
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Starter">Smart Starter</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Medium">Smart Medium</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Business">Smart Business</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Deluxe">Smart Deluxe</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>$ 2.90</td>
                        <td>$ 5.90</td>
                        <td>$ 9.90</td>
                        <td>$ 14.90</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>512 MB</td>
                        <td>1 GB</td>
                        <td>2 GB</td>
                        <td>4 GB</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>50 GB</td>
                        <td>100 GB</td>
                        <td>150 GB</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>19.90 $</td>
                        <td>12.90 $</td>
                        <td>free</td>
                        <td>free</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
    <table id="3">
        <thead>
              <div id="content">
            <a class="back" href="#"></a>
            <span class="scroll"></span>
            <p class="head">    
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Starter">Smart Starter</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Medium">Smart Medium</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Business">Smart Business</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Deluxe">Smart Deluxe</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>$ 2.90</td>
                        <td>$ 5.90</td>
                        <td>$ 9.90</td>
                        <td>$ 14.90</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>512 MB</td>
                        <td>1 GB</td>
                        <td>2 GB</td>
                        <td>4 GB</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>50 GB</td>
                        <td>100 GB</td>
                        <td>150 GB</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>19.90 $</td>
                        <td>12.90 $</td>
                        <td>free</td>
                        <td>free</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
      <table id="4">
        <thead>
              <div id="content">
            <a class="back" href="#"></a>
            <span class="scroll"></span>
            <p class="head">    
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Starter">Smart Starter</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Medium">Smart Medium</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Business">Smart Business</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Deluxe">Smart Deluxe</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>$ 2.90</td>
                        <td>$ 5.90</td>
                        <td>$ 9.90</td>
                        <td>$ 14.90</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>512 MB</td>
                        <td>1 GB</td>
                        <td>2 GB</td>
                        <td>4 GB</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>50 GB</td>
                        <td>100 GB</td>
                        <td>150 GB</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>19.90 $</td>
                        <td>12.90 $</td>
                        <td>free</td>
                        <td>free</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="check"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Css:

```
/* Table 3 Style */
table.table3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    text-align:center;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.table3 thead th{
    padding:6px 10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#444;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
    border-bottom:5px solid #444;
}
.table3 thead th:empty{
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
}
.table3 thead :nth-child(2),
.table3 tfoot :nth-child(2){
    background-color: #7FD2FF;
}
.table3 tfoot :nth-child(2){
    -moz-border-radius:0px 0px 0px 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}
.table3 thead :nth-child(2){
    -moz-border-radius:5px 0px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
}
.table3 thead :nth-child(3),
.table3 tfoot :nth-child(3){
    background-color: #45A8DF;
}
.table3 thead :nth-child(4),
.table3 tfoot :nth-child(4){
    background-color: #2388BF;
}
.table3 thead :nth-child(5),
.table3 tfoot :nth-child(5){
    background-color: #096A9F;
}
.table3 thead :nth-child(5){
    -moz-border-radius:0px 5px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
}
.table3 tfoot :nth-child(5){
    -moz-border-radius:0px 0px 5px 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}
.table3 tfoot td{
    font-size:38px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:15px 0px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.table3 tbody td{
    padding:10px;
}
.table3 tbody tr:nth-child(4) td{
    font-size:26px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.table3 tbody td:nth-child(even){
    background-color:#444;
    color:#444;
    border-bottom:1px solid #444;
    background:-webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.39, rgb(189,189,189)),
        color-stop(0.7, rgb(224,224,224))
        );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(
        center bottom,
        rgb(189,189,189) 39%,
        rgb(224,224,224) 70%
        );
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.table3 tbody td:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:#555;
    color:#f0f0f0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #444;
    background:-webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.39, rgb(85,85,85)),
        color-stop(0.7, rgb(105,105,105))
        );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(
        center bottom,
        rgb(85,85,85) 39%,
        rgb(105,105,105) 70%
        );
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}
.table3 tbody td:nth-last-child(1){
    border-right:1px solid #222;
}
.table3 tbody th{
    color:#696969;
    text-align:right;
    padding:0px 10px;
    border-right:1px solid #aaa;
}
.table3 tbody span.check::before{
    content : url(../images/check2.png)
}
```

Java:

```
(function () {
    var tables = $("table");
    //Grabs all the tables
    tables.hide().first().show();
    //Hides all the tables except first
    $("a.button").on("click", function () {
        //Adds eventListner to buttons
        tables.hide();
        //Hides all the tables
        var tableTarget = $(this).data("table");
        //Gets data# of button
        $("table#" + tableTarget).show();
        //Shows the table with an id equal to data attr of the button
    })
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not adding classes to your tables, so the CSS isn't even doing anything. Seems really simple, unless I'm missing something

```
<table id="1" class="table3">
<table id="2" class="table3">
<table id="3" class="table3">
<table id="4" class="table3">
```

`.table3` in css means everything that has a class named "table3"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not closing your tables. You've left every table open, so jQuery doesn't see any full table elements.

Check out this modified fiddle I updated for you. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LpLhP/6/)

```
<table id="1">...</table>
<table id="2">...</table>
<table id="3">...</table>
<table id="4">...</table>
```

Go through your markup and close any open tags and you'll be set.

Comment: I just realized I read your question incorrectly. However the point does stand: you should edit your markup and close the open tags